# UIButton selector not working on mainwindow view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

I am adding a custom view on main window then on the view i am creating a button and button is showing but the action is not performing on button tapped.
on a button tap i want to open a photogallery.
and in a loop the buttons are created.

code that i am using is there...

```
UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data cache:NO];
UIImageView *iv=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, y, 75, 75)];

UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, y, 75, 75)];
[button setAlpha:0];
[button setTag:i];//change this to your loop counter
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  

iv.image=image;
//  iv.tag=@"bigimage.jpg";
iv.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[iv addSubview:button];
[button release];

y=y+145;
[view1 addSubview:iv];
[iv release];
```

And also try this code but no improvements are there.....

```
UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame=CGRectMake(200, y, 75, 75);
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        [button setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag = i;
        y = y+145;
        [view1 addSubview:button];
```

Comment: Why are you adding your button to a image view?

Comment: because i have to display a image on button not the title.

Comment: @shivangi : then you should add image as button's background image.

Comment: I have made image as a background imgae but the problem still remains the same.

Comment: OR you also can put button on image view. Make a transparent(custom) button and put it on image view.

Comment: that i already done on the above code but it's not working.

Comment: you dont need this line [iv addSubview:button]; add your button on your view not IN the image view

Comment: try to create button by this way :
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(200, y, 75, 75);

Comment: maulik thanks for replying but i already tried that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Shivangi,

```
         I think you want to set image on button so try this code its will help you



          //function to create button dynamically on scrollview
          -(void)createButton
           {
            int Y = 20;
            indexRow = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < [prow.noOfPhotos count]; i++) 
            {
              thumbNailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];       
              int X = 4 + (78 * (i % 4));
              NSLog(@"X = %d",X);

              NSLog(@"Start Y = %d",Y);
              if (i % 4 == 0) 
              {
            NSLog(@"%d",i);
            Y = (70 * verticalImageRowCount);
            NSLog(@"Y = %d",Y);
            verticalImageRowCount++;
            NSLog(@"VerticalImageRowCount= %d");
              } 

              CGRect rect = myScrollView.frame;
               rect.size.width = 100;
               rect.size.height = Y + 77; 
               myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width,rect.size.height);
               thumbNailButton.frame = CGRectMake(X,Y, 62,65);

               view = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

               prow.photo = [prow.noOfPhotos objectAtIndex:indexRow];

               imagePath = prow.photo;
               asyncImageView = [[[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 0, 62, 65)] autorelease];
               asyncImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
               [view addSubview:asyncImageView];

               NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imagePath];
               [asyncImageView loadImageFromURL:url];           
               [view setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[prow.noOfPhotos objectAtIndex:i]]];

               thumbNailButton.tag = i;
               thumbNailButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
                   [thumbNailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];   
               [thumbNailButton addSubview:view];
               [myScrollView addSubview:thumbNailButton];
               indexRow+= 1;

                }
                }
```

Comment: after doing this my problem remains same.

Comment: I think u want to implement photo gallery functionality

Answer (score 1):

The frame of your button should not have the same origin x and y as your imageview. If you want it inside the image view it should have origin x:0 y:0 and the same width and height as your imageview.

The origin x,y is relative to it's parent. In your case the imageview.

Comment: And I agree Nikunj, why not have a image as background on the button instead?

Comment: what does you buttonPressed method look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an NSLog in your buttonPressed: and see if that method is getting called. Maybe the method is getting called but the Photo Gallery app isn't launching for some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

The user cannot click the button if you set the button's alpha to 0. This means the event will not be fired.

```
[button setAlpha:0];
```

This has the same effect as setting button.hidden = YES.

If you want an invisible clickzone using the button, set the button type to UIButtonTypeCustom and it should do the trick.